# Page numbering Total pages and sectioning

Tags: adobe-indesign

Can I use both an auto page number marker that shows actual current page number as well as the section number on the same document?

Answer (score 1):

You unfortunately cannot do it using built-in INDD features.
So... Let's think different ^^

The idea is to create custom Numbered list for the custom numbering starting to 1 at each new section (did I understand the request correctly?)

1. Create a new list. *(let's call it "sections")*
2. Create a new paragraph style. *(let's call it "title")*
   Go numbering and bullets options, set it as numbered: level 1. Create a character style in order to set the numbering as invisible (no text color would do the job):

[image]

3. Create another paragraph style. *(let's call it "Custom section numbering")*.
   Go numbering and bullets options, set it as numbered: level 2 and check box "restart at any higher level"

[image]

4. Create a specific Master for first page of a new section. Create a new layer. On this layer, place a section mark in a frame, apply "Title" para style. Type a space anywhere you want you want your custom numbering and apply "Custom section numbering" style to it. If you want it inline after a section mark, for instance, you can use a table. Thread frames in order to have continuous levels.
   See example below:

[image: master]

4. Apply this Master to starting sections pages. Set Section Marker for each of them (if not done already).

[image]

5. Finally... Here's the tricky part, and the bad news. Lists would only work if unlocked. So you'll have to override them. Since you've placed them on a new layer (see 4.), it's easy to lock all layers except this one, to select all pages and to override all elements. (You can also use the "Deselect Allow Master Item Overrides On Selection" method. Up to you). Then, you're done. Now, obviously, you might want to move, delete or add pages. So this final "Override all elements" step has to be done at the very end. After moving, deleting or adding pages, just lock all other layers, select all pages, Reapply all, then Override all.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I think if you took 30 seconds to try this you'd discover you can easily.

[image]

Merely choose each option as you need it.

If the sections have markers set:

[image]

They will appear as set on the master page(s).

Comment: The issue is I have a document that already uses multiple sections.  (Species of wood so Oak page 1...14, Pine 1...12 etc. But the entire document is about 68 pages so i want the section numbering (Oak -3) and actual page number in the document (page 25) both showing on the page.

Comment: Ahh.. that's not what you asked. More detail in the question is *always* beneficial.

Comment: That is what I meant by "can I use both"  The only thing I can see to do is manually number the pages but as I want to be able to add product to each specie section this becomes cumbersome to go back and renumber the actual page numbers.